# React table - giving cells links

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table I want to give each cell a link. When you click on the data in the cell you need to be redirected to a new page. How would I do this?

My react table code is the following:

```
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: '',
        accessor: 'checked',
        Cell: () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        Header: 'User ID',
        accessor: 'id',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name',
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          return `${row.original.firstName} ${row.original.lastName}`;
        },
      },
      {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'email',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Mobile Number',
        accessor: 'mobileNumber',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Status',
        accessor: 'status',
      },
      {
        Header: '',
        accessor: 'action',
        Cell: () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Button className="text-black" title="Edit User Schedule" onClick={handleClick}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        },
      },
    ],
    [],
  );
```

The page I want to be redirected to id '/individual-user'

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Cell prop

```
Cell: ({ row }) => {
          return `<a href="/individual-user">${row.original.firstName} ${row.original.lastName}</a>`;
        },
```

Replace `a` with `Link` if you are using React router.

JSX should also work

```
 return <a href={`/${row.original.id}`}>{`${row.original.firstName} ${row.original.lastName}`}</a>
```

Comment: The jsx didnt take me to the page i need to go to?

Comment: Can i somehow add the link to the page in there?

Comment: Please post the link if its publicly accessible.